# I host my PHP website in infinityfree platform, but there is some error in timezone

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone, cpanel

I want to fetch the time from the database and want to show it to the user, but I saw the timezone inserted there, is absolutely wrong, I understood that the timezone is not 'Asia/Kolkata' in that server, but can I change it by function `date_default_timezone_set()` available in PHP, if not then how can I do it?

Comment: With ini_set() https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Answer (score 0):

Right after you connect from your php program to the database, give the SQL statement

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Halifax';
```

Put in your own time zone, obviously. Server time zones are usually set to UTC, but may be set to the local time of their owners. If you don't set your own time zone, you'll get the server's time zone, whatever it happens to be.